# Using Jquery, load select options on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load *options* into a *select* element when the user focuses.

Here is the jquery code I'm using:

```
$('select').focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('hasitems')) {
        var selectedValue = $this.val();

        $this.empty()
            .append($('<option></option')
            .attr('value','')
            .text('Loading...'));

        // This would usually be the result of an AJAX call
        $this.empty()
            .data('hasitems','true');

        $.each(['a','b','c','d'], function(index,item) {
            $this.append($('<option></option>')
                         .attr('value',item)
                         .text(item)
                         .prop('selected', selectedValue == item));
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/agnnC/

The solution *almost* works... except in Firefox (and sometimes not in Chrome either, although the fiddle I put together does appear to work).

The problem in Firefox is that when the user clicks on the select element, the currently selected value is not remembered and is changed to one of the new values in the drop down.

Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: you want user can not change value of drop-down ??

Comment: Could you populate the select as a result of a previous action? Seems safer for screen readers, at least. Also if you add `size="4"`, Firefox seems to behave as expected: that's really a problem with what is being shown without `size` I guess

Comment: @Tushar Gupta The users can still change the drop down after the options are loaded. See the fiddle.

Comment: @FelipAls The point is only to load the options into HTML when the user is interested in changing the currently selected value. There are alternative UI elements for achieving this feature, but this version would work most nicely. My users don't use screen readers.

Comment: what is the point of loading options only when user focuses on select? Seems to cause unexpected behavior. `a` gets set if focus away, but `c` is selected

Comment: I think we'd need to see the actual ajax call.  I suspect you may be having problems with the async nature of ajax calls and running code right after the ajax call and expecting it to be done, when the success handler hasn't been called yet.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, that unexpected behaviour you are observing is exactly what I am trying to resolve and why I posted on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, the problem exists without the ajax call - please see the fiddle.

Comment: I imagine older versions of IE wil throw fits too...surely there is another user interaction would allow you to populate ahead of time...or use a select replacement plugin

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I am aware of alternative UI elements, but I am only interested in this particular problem, which seems to really be a bug or silly behaviour of Firefox. There is no other previous user interaction which would indicate whether they planned on clicking on the select element.

Comment: sometimes smart to just abandon an idea that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `selected` attribute is not really a property the way you are using it.  Per the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):

> selected
>
> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is
>   initially selected. If the  element is the descendant of
>   a element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single
>    of this  element may have the selected attribute.

Note, it talks about "initially selected" only, not real time changes.  It also refers to selected only as an attribute, not a property.

The [W3C spec for the option element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) also talks only about pre-selecting an option, not about making live changes using the selected attribute.

Once the select and options are live, the `.selectedIndex` property on the `<select>` object controls which option is selected in real time for single selection select elements.

In support of this theory, if you change to setting the saved item with `.selectedIndex` as shown below, the problem goes away:

```
$('select').focus(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data('hasitems')) {
        var selectedValue = $this.val();

        $this.empty()
            .append($('<option></option')
            .attr('value','')
            .text('Loading...'));

        // This would usually be the result of an AJAX call
        $this.empty()
            .data('hasitems','true');

        $.each(['a','b','c','d'], function(index,item) {
            $this.append($('<option></option>')
                         .val(item)
                         .text(item));
            if (selectedValue == item) {
                $this.prop("selectedIndex", index);
            }        
        });
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4333d/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox can't change the focus `option` when `select` is opening, but you can change before it open, change the event to `mousedown` it working <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agnnC/10/)</kbd>

```
$('select').mousedown(function() {
  // ...
});
```